# Client Exception with neo4j Bolt Driver - Uniqueness Constraint violation with SDN save()

Tags: spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to use recently introduced Bolt Driver.
Following, is the dependency set that I am using for the purpose.

```
neo4j-ogm = 2.0.2
neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver = 2.0.2
spring-data-neo4j= 4.1.2.RELEASE
```

Also, there are some indexes created on nodes based on Uniqueness Constraints.

With above set up when I am trying to update a node with label X, and Uniqueness Constraint enabled on property Y using SDN's repo.save(Obj) method,
I receive **" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Node  already exists with label X and property Y"**. However, when I try to save/update 
the node with HTTP driver in the same set up, it works seamlessly.

Further debug reveals that with BOLT driver, the SDN sends CREATE Query to Neo4j server each time save() method is called even during update. This obviously violates the constraint. However, with HTTP driver
SDN sends CREATE only once during the node creation. After that subsequent updates are handled using MERGE.

It would be great if someone can clarify whether it is a bug on the SDN support for BOLT, or I am missing something over here.

Please let me know if further details are required.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, please open one at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues with an example/test?